# Can't setup dual monitor in Debian!

Tags: debian, display, laptop

I just got a new laptop and decided to try Debian on it, currently tracking "testing" repositories. It has both an integrated Intel GPU and an NVIDIA GPU. I installed the non-free "nvidia-driver" package and it seems to be working according to this command I found on a random forum somewhere, although I don't really know if them displaying as [VGA controller] is enough to say they are running correctly:

```
~$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3e9b] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] [10de:1c91] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I have an old TV I used as a second monitor when I used Ubuntu in the my old laptop. However, when I try to connect it in the HDMI port of the new computer, it doesn't seem to be recognized. The output from "xrandr" doesn't change whether the monitor is plugged in or not:

```
~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
1920x1080     59.96*+
```

On Windows 10 in the same machine the monitor works just fine, so I know it isn't a hardware problem. Any ideas on what the problem could be? If you need more details just ask.

Thanks!

Edit: Ran some other tests with "lshw -c display". It was showing the NVIDIA graphics card as UNCLAIMED, and I noticed the NVIDIA persistence daemon was not loading correctly on boot, whatever that is. After turning "Secure Boot" off in the BIOS the daemon loaded correctly and the GPU was not UNCLAIMED anymore.

Also, "xrandsr"'s output changed, but it's still the same whether the monitor is plugged in or not:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```